Andy Borg - Adios Amor: Erklärung zu "ich komm verlassen mir vor"
Ich bin auf Youtube einem Lied begegnet - Andy Borg - Adios Amor.
Im Refrain singt er:

Ich komm verlassen mir vor

Der ganze Refrain is so:

Ich weiß, dass ich dich verlor
Dass mit dir auch den Freund ich verlor
Ich komm verlassen mir vor
Drum adios, adios, adios Amor

Kann mir jemand den obengenannten Satz erklären? Ich kann ihn durchaus nicht verstehen.

Wo genau ist das Problem? Sowohl jemandem vorkommen als auch verlassen solltest du im Wörterbuch finden können, was ist sonst noch unklar?

@DonHolgo: Wahrscheinlich der Satzbau, der abseits von Lyrik eher befremdlich wirkt.

The word order is a little skewed because of "poetic" (which in this case is a strong word) license. There are also some letters dropped because when the lyrics make no sense they should at least rhyme. To put the words in regular order and reestablish the missing letters:

Ich weiß, dass ich dich verlor,
Dass ich mit dir auch den Freund verlor.
Ich komm(e) mir verlassen vor
D(a)rum adios, adios, adios, Amor

"Drum" instead of "darum" and "dropping the final "e" in verb conjugation is common in colloquial language (e.g. "komm her!" instead of "komme her!", come here!)

Why do you answer in English when the question was asked in German?

@infinitezero: das war ein Versehen.
